# Azure migrate from VMware host not found

Tags: azure, migration, azure-site-recovery

I am trying to migrate a VM from VMWare to Azure portal. the VM appliance is configured . But the hosts are not recognized . What is the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you mention 'Hosts are not recognized', are you unable to discover them via the Portal? or do you receive any specific error message? Are you using agentless or agent-based migration? Please do more details on your scenario:

Couple of things you could try to isolate the issue:

- Review the "Status" in the Azure Portal.

If this doesn't work and you're discovering VMware servers:

- Verify that the vCenter account you specified has permissions set
  correctly, with access to at least one VM.
- Azure Migrate can't discovered VMware VMs if the vCenter account has
  access granted at vCenter VM folder level. Learn more about scoping
  discovery. Kindly review the [requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/migrate/migrate-support-matrix-vmware-migration) and [common app discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/migrate/troubleshoot-appliance-discovery#common-app-discovery-errors) errors to tackle any errors you may be receiving.